# Comparative status of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum {a_n}^{[2]}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of real terms.

> I'm interested in finding a counter-example to the assertion $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\text{ converges }\implies\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}^{[2]}\text{ converges}$$

**Where $x^{[2]}=x^2\times \operatorname{sgn}(x)=x\,|x|$ is the odd square function.**

- If the sequence has only positive terms $a_n\ge 0$ or if $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent then it can be proven that $\sum {a_n}^2$ is absolutely convergent as well.

[$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges $\implies \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} a_n^2$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008442/sum-limitsn-0-infty-a-n-converges-implies-sum-limitsn-0-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Prove that if $\sum{a_n}$ converges absolutely, then $\sum{a_n^2}$ converges absolutely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493756/prove-that-if-suma-n-converges-absolutely-then-suma-n2-converges-abs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

- If the CAS (criteria of alternated series) is verified for $\sum a_n$ then it is also verified for $\sum {a_n}^{[2]}$ so both series are convergent.

Indeed if $|a_{n+1}|<|a_n|$ then since $x\mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0,+\infty[$ then $|a_{n+1}|^2\le|a_n|^2$

Also since $\operatorname{sgn}(a_n)=\operatorname{sgn}({a_n}^{[2]})$ they are both alternated series.

- Finally since $x\mapsto x^{[2]}$ is not linear in a neighbourhood of zero then it is not a convergence preserving function according to this result:

[$f$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \sum f(a_n)$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332433/f-such-that-sum-a-n-converges-implies-sum-fa-n-converges/1333652#1333652)

[The set of functions which map convergent series to convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116964/the-set-of-functions-which-map-convergent-series-to-convergent-series?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So it should be possible to exhibit a sequence $(a_n)_n$ such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent while $\sum {a_n}^{[2]}$ is not.

Unfortunately I haven't been very successful at expliciting such a sequence, in fact I was wondering if the theorem was not true after all until I found the postulate above regarding CP functions.

Do you know any counter-examples for the assertion at the beginning of the post ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice research. I can tell you've been searching. Here is a counterexample for the general $a_n$ converges implies $a_n^{[k]}$ converges (for $k \neq 1$). We can construct the series from groups of threes as follows.
$$\frac{1}{n^{1/k}} + \frac{1}{n^{1/k}} - \frac{2}{n^{1/k}}$$
This series converges as the sum of each set of three is $0$ and the limit of the terms is also $0$ as $n\to\infty$.  But when we take the $k$th power (keeping the sign) of each term, we end up with a constant multiple of the harmonic series.
$$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{2^k}{n}=(2-2^k)\frac{1}{n}$$
And as we all know, the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Arf, so simple when you see it ! I did not though about the null sequence.