# sum of alternating $|f|$ and $|f|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Does anyone know an example of a function $f$ for which the relation
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n |f(n)| < \infty \\
\Longleftrightarrow \\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n |f(n)|^2 < \infty
$$
is violated?

Even though the counterexamples are somewhat valid I was more thinking about a differentiable function $f(n)$, possibly even analytic.

In a similar manner: Does the following hold
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n |f(n)|^2 < \infty \\
\Longrightarrow \quad  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|f(n)|^2}{1+a^2 |f(n)|^2} < \infty
$$
where $a>0$ ? The last one is interesting, because for $a=0$ this matches the assumption and for $a \rightarrow \infty$ the sum is bounded as well since $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\right| \leq 1$.

If it is even possible to show
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|f(n)|^2}{1+a^2 |f(n)|^2} \sim {\cal O}\left(a^{-1-\epsilon}\right) \qquad {\rm as} \qquad a\rightarrow \infty
$$
and $\epsilon>0$ then the integral
$$
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n|f(n)|^2}{1+a^2 |f(n)|^2} \, {\rm d}a = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n |f(n)| < \infty
$$
is well defined and reproduces the first relation.

Comment: I think you mean an *example* for which the relation is violated. a counterexample to violating the biconditional would be an example showing it

Comment: True, I was thinking about a counterexample and ended the sentence wrong.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570953/comparative-status-of-sum-a-n-and-sum-a-n2 The counterexample by I.Browne can be adapted to your case by reindexing with $f(n)=0$ for unwanted terms. This time the first series is convergent while the second is not. In the other answers you get here, it is the opposite.

Comment: Good example for the other way around, but unfortunately still not analytic.

Answer (score 9):

You can put all the weight of the harmonic series on the terms with one sign. For instance 
$$
f (n)=\begin {cases}1/n,&n\ \text {odd},\\ \ \ 0,&n\ \text {even}\end {cases}
$$
makes the first series divergent and the second convergent.